# Embed sql query inside the Session asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, session

I have a problem that to embed sql query inside the Session. I want to load the page with sql query. If user has more than 5 number of records throw message. How can I do this? My query like below. Thanks for responses.

My page load like that

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(Session["User"] != null)
        {
            user = Session["User"] as User;

        }
        else
        {
            pnlgiris.Visible = false;
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "redirect",
                      "alert('Please login first'); window.location='" +
                      Request.ApplicationPath + "Home.aspx';", true);

        }

    }
```

I want to embed this query inside the session.

```
SELECT  Users.UserName, COUNT(Book.BookName) 
FROM Users
JOIN Book ON Users.UserId = Book.UserId  
GROUP BY Users.UserName 
HAVING COUNT(*) < 5;
```

My user class

```
 public class User
{      
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

User object on Login

```
  User u = new User();
                u.UserId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["UserId"]);
                u.UserName = dr["Name"] != DBNull.Value ? dr["Name"].ToString() : string.Empty;
                u.UserName = dr["Surname"] != DBNull.Value ? dr["Surname"].ToString() : string.Empty;
                u.UserName = dr["UserName"] != DBNull.Value ? dr["UserName"].ToString() : string.Empty;
                u.Email = dr["Email"] != DBNull.Value ? dr["Email"].ToString() : string.Empty;
                Session["User"] = u;
                Response.Redirect("~/Home.aspx");
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use a StringBuilder like this:

```
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("SELECT Users.UserName,");          
    sb.Append("COUNT(Book.BookName) ";
    sb.Append("FROM Users ");
    sb.Append("JOIN Book ON Users.UserId = Book.UserId ");
    sb.Append("GROUP BY Users.UserName ");
    sb.Append("HAVING COUNT(*) < 5;");
    Session["SomeSql"] = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: This is a terrible way to build a string. If your string is literal then just declare it. Even if you use the `+` operator on literals the compiler will combine it to avoid concatenations.

Comment: You are certainly a novice developer as everyone knows that using the + operator creates a new string for every concatenation whereas StringBuilder does not.

Comment: [Concatenation is the process of appending one string to the end of another string. When you concatenate string literals or string constants by using the + operator, the compiler creates a single string. No run time concatenation occurs.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228504.aspx)

Comment: on the contrary, it is the novice developer that thinks `StringBuilder` is more efficient than doing a small number of string concatenations. `String.Format`, `String.Concat` and `+` are all more efficient **up to a point**. `StringBuilder` is intended for cases where there are enough concatenations to make it the appropriate choice. Your answer not only gives bad concatenation advice, it doesn't even answer the question.